# How to loc value in Rust Polars?

Tags: python, rust, python-polars, rust-polars

In Pandas or Polars-Python, we can loc a value by using `iloc` `loc` or `[1,2]`. How could we do the same thing in Polars with Rust?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide explaining this in great detail:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/indexing.html

In short, Polars uses direct indexing in lieu of `loc`/`iloc`.

The guide lists a lot of helpful examples.

Comment: The example is python. How would you do something like df[:2] in pure Rust?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.take`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.take).

> ```
> pub fn take(
>     &self,
>     indices: &ChunkedArray<UInt32Type>
> ) -> Result<DataFrame, PolarsError>
> ```
>
> Take DataFrame rows by index values.

For example to select the second and third row, you could do:

```
use polars::datatypes::IdxCa;
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let df = df! [
        "names" => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
        "values" => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    ]
    .unwrap();

    let indices = IdxCa::new("idx", 1..3);
    let new_df = df.take(&indices).unwrap();

    println!("{}", new_df);
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────┬────────┐
│ names ┆ values │
│ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ i32    │
╞═══════╪════════╡
│ b     ┆ 2      │
│ c     ┆ 3      │
└───────┴────────┘
```